# one javascript controlling two separate browser windows.

Tags: javascript

I am building a so called random art generator using the HTML5 canvas element. Now I want the buttons that control the visual action on the canvas in realtime to be in a separate window. Is there a way to do that? I suppose I need one javascript controlling two separate browser windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cross-document messaging provided that your two pages are from the same origin (protocol, hostname, port). This is how it is done:

On your page that should send information (that with your buttons) you invoke this:

```
window.postMessage(message, origin);
```

which will send the message provided to the origin given (the url of your other page).

On your receving page you include this function:

```
window.addEventListener("message", yourfunction);
```

where `yourfunction` takes an argument, `e`. `e` is of the type MessageEvent and contains the following properties:

- data
- origin
- source (Returns the window associated with the sending script.)

And that's all there is to it!

Comment: Did this help you out at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need communication API for Cross Document Messaging.

You can use `postMessage` to send and receive messages.

```
//Post message
window.postMessage('Hello world...', 'http://example.com');

//Bind events
window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, true);
```

Also don't forget to check browser support:

```
if(typeof window.postMessage === "undefined"){
   alert('Your browser doesnt support this functionality');
}
```

[This tutorial might be usefull.](http://72lions.com/2011/05/cross-origin-communication-with-html5)